# Use mariaDb with Clion and Cmake in C

Tags: mysql, c, cmake, mariadb, clion

I'm trying to use mariadb in my C application, normally I run my application with a make file containing the following code:
`` gcc -g src/*.c -o applicazione `mariadb_config --cflags --include --libs` ``

I am trying to use Clion and Cmakelist with the following code:

```
project(project C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

FIND_LIBRARY(mariadb mariadb)


include_directories(/usr/include/mariadb)
link_directories(/usr/include/mariadb)

include_directories(/usr/include/mariadb/mysql)
link_directories(/usr/include/mariadb/mysql)


add_executable(project main.c file1.c file2.c file3.c)
```

But I get this compilation error, and other similar errors for other mysql functions:

```
 undefined reference to `mysql_error'
```

I think this library `libmariadbclient.so` is missing to insert but I can't do it

Comment: Did you look up how to use a library in cmake?

Comment: You forgot `target_link_libraries` call which performs linking. The duplicate question and its answers describe how this call could be written.

Comment: i didn't quite understand how to link the target library. I try this `find_library(maria_db_lib libmariadbclient)

target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE "${maria_db_lib}") ` but I get the error:   `Cannot specify link libraries for target "project" which is not built by
  this project`. I think the library path is this: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so`

Comment: `target_link_libraries` call should come **after** `add_executable` one. Look, call to `target_link_libraries(project ...)` uses `project` target which is defined only with `add_executable(project ...)` call.

Comment: thanks, I use `target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE libmariadbclient.so)` after `add_executable(project ...)` and now it work